# Enumerating and Switching Wireless Profiles in WM6 without using OpenNetCF

Tags: c#, wireless, windows-mobile-6

I'm trying to enumerate and switch wireless profiles under Windows Mobile 6. The unit that I'm using is the SocketMobile 650. I've pretty much ruled out using OpenNetCF to accomplish this, since the GetAllNetworkInterfaces() call returns a wifi network interface that doesn't appear to advertise itself as WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface (or even WirelessNetworkInterface, for that matter).

So, I'm back to looking at API calls. My question is: How can I use c# to enumerate and switch wireless profiles without using OpenNetCF?

Comment: is it still an issue? would you consider unmanaged DLL and managed interface for it? Few years ago i did something similar - i was using NDIS on unmanaged side. If you consider this - i will post the codes. PLease let me know.

Comment: Sure. I'd already resigned myself to needing to use API's, so if you even have wrappers around them already, that's even better.

Comment: i started to write an answer and realized that you are talking about wireless profiles - do you mean access points, or something else?

Comment: Yes, if you go to Start -> Settings -> Connections (tab) -> Wifi, I'm looking to work with the items in this list.

Comment: sorry, i was talking about access points originally, i have codes to list them but not the profiles :(

Comment: This may be the same. Can you post the code? Does your code also support switching between the access points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, looks like SO "insert code" does not handle long code listings well, so codes look bad. Please copy/paste them into your editor, and do reformatting.

items (1), (2), (3) are quite trivial - they are just definitions of classes/structs/export functions. Item (4) is where all magic happens - but i was not able to insert it here  (too long), so I copied it to PasteBin (link is below). Please let me know if you have any questions - i will try to help you - but idea is to use DeviceIoControl low-level function to communicate with the adapter.

---

please take a look at the codes. I don't think you will be able to compile them, however they should give you an idea what's going on under the hood. Disclaimer - i wrote them 5-6 years ago, and now i would do it quite different :)

1. C# wrapper for C++ dll:

   public class WiFiDllWrapper
   {
       private class DllFunctions
       {
           [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
           internal static extern bool TurnWlanOn();

   ```
       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool FindWirelessAdapter();

       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool ConnectToAdapter();

       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool DisconnectFromAdapter();

       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool StartScan();

       // gets a list of APs from NIC
       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool GetAPsList([In, Out] APInfo[] pAPs, int maxAPs, ref int foundAPs);

       // connects to a selected AP
       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool ConnectToAP(int maxWaitTimeSeconds, string ssid, bool isWepEnabled, string wepKey);

       [DllImport("ewf.dll")]
       internal static extern bool RenewIPAddress(int maxWaitTimeSeconds);

   }

   public static bool TurnWlanOn()
   {
       return DllFunctions.TurnWlanOn();
   }

   public static bool FindWirelessAdapter()
   {
       return DllFunctions.FindWirelessAdapter();
   }

   public static bool ConnectToNdis()
   {
       bool bDisableWzcViaDriver = (Settings.GetOSVersion() != OSVersion.WM2003);

       bool bRes = DllFunctions.ConnectToAdapter();

       return bRes;
   }

   public static bool DisconnectFromNdis()
   {
       return DllFunctions.DisconnectFromAdapter();
   }

   public static void StartScan()
   {
       DllFunctions.StartScan();
   }

   public static bool ConnectToAP(int maxWaitTimeSeconds, string ssid, bool isWepEnabled, string wepKey)
   {
       DllFunctions.ConnectToAP(maxWaitTimeSeconds, ssid, isWepEnabled, wepKey);
       return true;
   }

   public static bool RenewIPAddress(int maxWaitTimeSeconds)
   {
       return DllFunctions.RenewIPAddress(maxWaitTimeSeconds);
   }


   public static List<AccessPoint> GetAPsList()
   {
       int numberOfItems = 0;  // gets a number of actually found devices
       APInfo[] OutputList = new APInfo[30];

       if (DllFunctions.GetAPsList(OutputList, OutputList.Length, ref numberOfItems) == false)
           throw new Exception("AP scan failed!");

       List<AccessPoint> lst = new List<AccessPoint>();
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
           lst.Add(new AccessPoint(OutputList[i]));

       return lst;
   }
   ```

   }
2. AccessPoint model definition:

   ```
   // just took enums from NTDDNDIS.H file...
   ```

   enum NDIS_802_11_WEP_STATUS
   {
       Ndis802_11WEPEnabled,
       Ndis802_11Encryption1Enabled = Ndis802_11WEPEnabled,
       Ndis802_11WEPDisabled,
       Ndis802_11EncryptionDisabled = Ndis802_11WEPDisabled,
       Ndis802_11WEPKeyAbsent,
       Ndis802_11Encryption1KeyAbsent = Ndis802_11WEPKeyAbsent,
       Ndis802_11WEPNotSupported,
       Ndis802_11EncryptionNotSupported = Ndis802_11WEPNotSupported,
       Ndis802_11Encryption2Enabled,
       Ndis802_11Encryption2KeyAbsent,
       Ndis802_11Encryption3Enabled,
       Ndis802_11Encryption3KeyAbsent
   };

   enum NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_INFRASTRUCTURE
   {
       Ndis802_11IBSS,
       Ndis802_11Infrastructure,
       Ndis802_11AutoUnknown,
       Ndis802_11InfrastructureMax         // Not a real value, defined as upper bound
   };

   enum NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE
   {
       Ndis802_11FH,
       Ndis802_11DS,
       Ndis802_11OFDM5,            // Added new types for OFDM 5G and 2.4G
       Ndis802_11OFDM24,
       Ndis802_11NetworkTypeMax    // not a real type, defined as an upper bound
   };

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   struct APInfo
   {
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
       public string _ssid;    // SSID of the AP

   ```
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
   public string _mac; // MAC address of the AP

   //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   public int _rssi;   // signal strength in dB
   //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   public uint _wepStatus;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
   public NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_INFRASTRUCTURE _networkInfrastructure;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
   public NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE _networkType;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   public uint BeaconPeriod;       // units are Kusec

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   public uint DSConfig;           // Frequency, units are kHz

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
   public byte[] _rates;          // MSDN: Each byte describes a single rate in units of 0.5 Mbps
   ```

   }

   public class AccessPoint
   {
       //  if the power level (in dBm) lower that this, then the signal is weak
       const int STRONG_WEEK_dBm_THRESHOLD = -70;

   ```
   public static bool IsSignalWeak(int SignalStrengthdBm)
   {
       return SignalStrengthdBm < STRONG_WEEK_dBm_THRESHOLD;
   }


   internal AccessPoint(APInfo apInfo)
   {
       _ssid = apInfo._ssid;
       _mac = apInfo._mac;
       _rssi = apInfo._rssi;
       _wepStatus = apInfo._wepStatus;

       _networkInfrastructure = apInfo._networkInfrastructure;
       _networkType = apInfo._networkType;
       BeaconPeriod = apInfo.BeaconPeriod;
       DSConfig = apInfo.DSConfig;
       _rates = apInfo._rates;
   }

   private string _ssid;   // SSID of the AP
   private string _mac;    // MAC address of the AP

   private int _rssi;  // signal strength in dB
   private uint _wepStatus;
   private NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_INFRASTRUCTURE _networkInfrastructure;
   private NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE _networkType;

   private uint BeaconPeriod;      // units are Kusec

   private uint DSConfig;          // Frequency, units are kHz

   private byte[] _rates;          // MSDN: Each byte describes a single rate in units of 0.5 Mbps


   public bool IsEncrypted
   {
       get
       {
           return _wepStatus != 0;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Beacon Interval in ms
   /// </summary>
   public ulong BeaconInterval
   {
       get { return BeaconPeriod; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Frequency in MHz
   /// </summary>
   public ulong Frequency
   {
       get { return (DSConfig / 1000); }
   }


   /// <summary>
   /// Supported Rates by AP. Part of them belongs to Basic Rate Set.
   /// </summary>
   public string Rates
   {
       get
       {

           Array.Sort(_rates);

           string basicRateSet = "", notBasicRateSet = "";
           for (int i = 0; i < _rates.Length; i++)
           {
               if (_rates[i] == 0)
                   continue;

               // Each supported rate from the BSSBasicRateSet is encoded as a byte with the most significant bit (bit 7) set to 1. 
               if ((_rates[i] & (1 << 7)) > 0)
                   basicRateSet += ((_rates[i] - 128) / 2).ToString() + "; ";
               // Rates that are not included in the BSSBasicRateSet are encoded with the most significant bit set to zero. 
               else
                   notBasicRateSet += (_rates[i] / 2).ToString() + "; ";
           }

           return "BSSBasicRateSet: {" + basicRateSet + "}. other: {" + notBasicRateSet + "}";
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Number of wireless channel
   /// </summary>
   public ulong Channel
   {
       get
       {
           ulong centralFreqMHz = DSConfig / 1000;

           if (centralFreqMHz > 2400 && centralFreqMHz < 2500)      // then this is 802.11b/g
           {
               /*
               Regional allocated use of 802.11b/g channels  
                   1 to 11 -- North America (USA and Canada) 
                   1 to 13 -- Austria, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg,  Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom.
                   1 to 14 -- Japan, China, Hong Kong, Philippines, Taiwan, Thailand, Singapore, South Korea 
               */

               switch (centralFreqMHz)
               {
                   case 2412:
                       return 1;
                   case 2417:
                       return 2;
                   case 2422:
                       return 3;
                   case 2427:
                       return 4;
                   case 2432:
                       return 5;
                   case 2437:
                       return 6;
                   case 2442:
                       return 7;
                   case 2447:
                       return 8;
                   case 2452:
                       return 9;
                   case 2457:
                       return 10;
                   case 2462:
                       return 11;
                   case 2467:
                       return 12;
                   case 2472:
                       return 13;
                   case 2484:
                       return 14;

                   default:
                       return 0;
               }
           }
           else if (centralFreqMHz > 5100 && centralFreqMHz < 5900)       // this is 802.11a
           {
               switch (centralFreqMHz)
               {
                   case 5170:
                       return 34;
                   case 5180:
                       return 36;
                   case 5190:
                       return 38;
                   case 5200:
                       return 40;
                   case 5210:
                       return 42;
                   case 5220:
                       return 44;
                   case 5230:
                       return 46;
                   case 5240:
                       return 48;
                   case 5260:
                       return 52;
                   case 5280:
                       return 56;
                   case 5300:
                       return 60;
                   case 5320:
                       return 64;
                   case 5500:
                       return 100;
                   case 5520:
                       return 104;
                   case 5540:
                       return 108;
                   case 5560:
                       return 112;
                   case 5580:
                       return 116;
                   case 5600:
                       return 120;
                   case 5620:
                       return 124;
                   case 5640:
                       return 128;
                   case 5660:
                       return 132;
                   case 5680:
                       return 136;
                   case 5700:
                       return 140;
                   case 5745:
                       return 149;
                   case 5765:
                       return 153;
                   case 5785:
                       return 157;
                   case 5805:
                       return 161;

                   default:
                       return 0;
               }
           }
           else
               return 0;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// SSID of the AP
   /// </summary>
   public string SSID
   {
       get { return _ssid; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   ///  MAC address "XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX"
   /// </summary>
   public string MAC
   {
       get { return _mac; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Signal strength in dB
   /// </summary>
   public int SignalStrength
   {
       get { return (int)_rssi; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// MSDN:
   /// Specifies a WEP/WPA/WPA2 encryption requirement. A value of 0 indicates that privacy is disabled. 
   /// A value of 1 indicates that privacy is enabled. 
   /// </summary>
   public string WEP
   {
       get { return (_wepStatus == 0 ? "WEP disabled" : "WEP enabled"); }
   }


   /// <summary>
   /// Indicates the physical layer for the AP
   /// </summary>
   public string NetworkType
   {
       get
       {
           if (_networkType == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE.Ndis802_11FH)
               return "frequency-hopping spread-spectrum PHY";
           else if (_networkType == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE.Ndis802_11DS)
               return "direct-sequence spread-spectrum PHY";
           else if (_networkType == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE.Ndis802_11OFDM24)
               return "OFDM 2.4 GHz";
           else if (_networkType == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_TYPE.Ndis802_11OFDM5)
               return "OFDM 5 GHz";
           else
               return "PHY is not FH, nor DS";
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Indicates current network mode for AP
   /// </summary>
   public string NetworkMode
   {
       get
       {
           if (_networkInfrastructure == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_INFRASTRUCTURE.Ndis802_11IBSS)
               return "IBSS (ad hoc) mode";
           else if (_networkInfrastructure == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_INFRASTRUCTURE.Ndis802_11Infrastructure)
               return "Infrastructure (ESS) mode";
           else if (_networkInfrastructure == NDIS_802_11_NETWORK_INFRASTRUCTURE.Ndis802_11AutoUnknown)
               return "Automatic network mode";
           else
               return "not specified";
       }

   }
   ```

   }
3. C++ file #1 - exportable functions:

   ## include "stdafx.h"

   ## include "ewf.h"

## include "NdisConnect.h"

## include

NdisConnect g_NdisAdapter(L"ewf_log.txt");

extern HANDLE g_NdisConnectedEvent;

extern "C" EWF_API BOOL WINAPI FindWirelessAdapter()
{
    ENTER;

```
try
{
    return g_NdisAdapter.FindWirelessAdapter();
}
catch (NdisException* e)
{
    LOG_EXCEPTION(e);
    return FALSE;       
}

LEAVE;
return TRUE;
```

}

// 1. init adapter: CreateFile(NDISUIO_DEVICE_NAME, - done at g_NdisAdapter ctor
// 2. disable WZC
// 3. rebind adapter
// 4. open adapter
extern "C" EWF_API BOOL WINAPI ConnectToAdapter()
{
    ENTER;

```
try
{
    if (FALSE == g_NdisAdapter.FindWirelessAdapter())
        return FALSE;

    if (false == g_NdisAdapter.DisableWZC_Driver())
        g_NdisAdapter.DisableWZC_API();

    g_NdisAdapter.RebindAdapter();
    g_NdisAdapter.OpenDevice();
}
catch (NdisException* e)
{
    LOG_EXCEPTION(e);
    return FALSE;       
}

LEAVE;
return TRUE;
```

}

extern "C" EWF_API BOOL WINAPI TurnWlanOn()
{
    return g_NdisAdapter.TurnWlanOn();
}

extern "C" EWF_API BOOL WINAPI DisconnectFromAdapter()
{
    ENTER;
    try
    {
        g_NdisAdapter.Disassociate();
    }
    catch (NdisException* e)
    {
        LOG_EXCEPTION(e);
        return FALSE;
    }

```
LEAVE;
return TRUE;
```

}

extern "C" EWF_API BOOL StartScan()
{
    ENTER;
    g_NdisAdapter.ScanForAPs();

```
return TRUE;
```

}

extern "C" EWF_API BOOL GetAPsList(APInfo* pAPs, int maxAPs, int* foundAPs)
{
    ENTER;
    BOOL res = FALSE;

```
try
{
    res = g_NdisAdapter.GetAPList(pAPs, maxAPs, foundAPs);
}
catch (NdisException* e)
{
    LOG_EXCEPTION(e);
    return FALSE;
}

LEAVE;
return TRUE;
```

}

extern "C" EWF_API BOOL ConnectToAP(int maxWaitTimeSeconds, const wchar_t* ssid, bool isWepEnabled, const wchar_t* wepKey)
{
    char cSSID[33], cWepKey[30];
    localFunctionCT2A(ssid, cSSID, sizeof(cSSID));
    localFunctionCT2A(wepKey, cWepKey, sizeof(cWepKey));

```
ENTER_FUNC("SSID = " << cSSID << ", wep enabled = " << isWepEnabled << ", wep key = '" << cWepKey << "'");

g_NdisAdapter.Disassociate();

Sleep(2000);

ResetEvent(g_NdisConnectedEvent);
g_NdisAdapter.ConnectToAP(cSSID, isWepEnabled, cWepKey);

if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(g_NdisConnectedEvent, maxWaitTimeSeconds*1000))
{
    LOG("Did not get CONNECTED event from NDIS...");
    return FALSE;
}

LEAVE;
return TRUE;
```

}

1. NdisConnect class - all NDIS magic happens here:

<< when i pasted code here, i went well over 30k limit for the post, so I created PasteBin file>> - http://pastebin.com/wMBZAYCQ

Comment: Can you recreate a new pastebin file, or something more permanent? I'm getting a 404.

Comment: pls let me know if you have any questions/issues with the codes.

Comment: Right now that project is in the wings. It'll probably be at least a month until I get a chance to try out your code. :(